# Eclipse Plugin for internationalization i18n testing

Tags: java, internationalization, eclipse-plugin

I was wondering if any of you knew of eclipse plugins that scan your code for internationalization issues? Things like embedded strings or locale-sensitive methods.

I looked on google and there were alot of articles on HOW to internationalize an eclipse plugin but none that support it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe internationalization is a complex issue, and every language/framework/you-name-it which deals with i18n does it differently. So, my guess is there is no such plugin, and will not be in the near future.

The only plugin I found is [Eclipse I18N Properties File Editor](http://sourceforge.net/projects/epfe/) which addresses a specific file type, but chances are you don't need this one in particular.

Comment: Thanks I did a little more research and seems like there is a commercial one: http://www.kokusaika.jp/product/wwnavi.html. I wonder if there are open source projects similar to this...

Answer (score 2):

The closest you can get in Java is with the help of below tools

1. [getext-commons](http://code.google.com/p/gettext-commons/) - it can help you in Easy extraction of user visible strings etc
2. [JRC Editor](http://www.zaval.org/products/jrc-editor/) - it can help you in managing resource bundles. For e.g. it can tell you if a given key has translation missing for any supported locale of your application

Answer (score 0):

Although this is an old question, thought to share TapiJI as a good option in case someone is still searching

https://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/tapiji/